# How to filter on partial match using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I'm new to sparklyr (but familiar with spark and pyspark), and I've got a really basic question. I'm trying to filter a column based on a partial match. In dplyr, i'd write my operation as so:

```
businesses %>%
  filter(grepl('test', biz_name)) %>%
  head
```

Running that code on a spark dataframe however gives me:

> Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'GREPL'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'project_eftpos_failure'.; line 5 pos 7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same as in standard Spark, you can use either `rlike` (Java regular expressions):

```
df <- copy_to(sc, iris) 

df %>% filter(rlike(Species, "osa"))

# or anchored
df %>% filter(rlike(Species, "^.*osa.*$"))
```

or `like` (simple SQL regular expressions):

```
df %>% filter(like(Species, "%osa%"))
```

Both methods can be also used with suffix notation as

```
df %>% filter(Species %rlike%  "^.*osa.*$")
```

and

```
df %>% filter(Species %like% "%osa%")
```

respectively.

For details see `vignette("sql-translation")`.

Comment: Perfect, so simple :O i'm surprised i didn't find that listed anywhere else or on here: https://spark.rstudio.com/articles/guides-dplyr.html#sql-translation

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rookieerror, but the link is dead now.

Comment: You can use the Hive Operators and User-Defined Functions (UDFs) https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF