# Creating new variable by matching on strings in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I'm using sparklyr for the first time and I'm having trouble matching strings of two vectors to create a new variable at scale. My problem has the following general structure:

I have one large dataset of urls:

```
df_1 <-  data.frame(
  col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  col2 = c("john.com/abcd", "ringo.com/defg", "paul.com/hijk", "george.com/lmno", "rob.com/pqrs", "sam.com/tuvw", 
           "matt.com/xyza", "lenny.com/bcde", "bob.com/fghi", "tom.com/jklm"))
```

```
col1            col2
 1   john.com/abcd
 2  ringo.com/defg
 3   paul.com/hijk
 4 george.com/lmno
 5    rob.com/pqrs
 6    sam.com/tuvw
 7   matt.com/xyza
 8  lenny.com/bcde
 9    bob.com/fghi
10    tom.com/jklm
```

And another smaller dataset of general domains:

```
df_2 <- data.frame( 
  col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  col2 = c("john.com", "jake.com", "tim.com", "paul.com", "rob.com", "harry.com", "chris.com"))
```

```
col1      col2
    1  john.com
    2  jake.com
    3   tim.com
    4  paul.com
    5   rob.com
    6 harry.com
    7 chris.com
```

I want to use the vector of domains in df_2 (df_2$col2) to create a dummy variable for df_1 that indicates if the domain occurs within the urls in df_1 (df_1$col_2). The resulting dataframe should look like df_3.

```
df_3 <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  col2 = c("john.com/abcd", "ringo.com/defg", "paul.com/hijk", "george.com/lmno", "rob.com/pqrs", "sam.com/tuvw", 
               "matt.com/xyza", "lenny.com/bcde", "bob.com/fghi", "tom.com/jklm"),
  col3 = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0))
```

```
   col1            col2 col3
     1   john.com/abcd    1
     2  ringo.com/defg    0
     3   paul.com/hijk    1
     4 george.com/lmno    0
     5    rob.com/pqrs    1
     6    sam.com/tuvw    0
     7   matt.com/xyza    0
     8  lenny.com/bcde    0
     9    bob.com/fghi    0
    10    tom.com/jklm    0
```

I have read this post: [How to filter on partial match using sparklyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289490/how-to-filter-on-partial-match-using-sparklyr)

And have tried coding this for each individual observation of df_2 with something like,

```
df_3 <- df_1 %>%
  mutate(col3 = 
    ifelse(like(df_1$col2, "john.com") | df_1$col2, "jake.com" | etc.,1,0))
```

But so far I have been running into either stack limits or R not recognizing the like functions. There must be an easier way to do this. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a well defined prefix like here, you can extract it:

```
sdf_1 <- copy_to(sc, df_1)
sdf_2 <- copy_to(sc, df_2)

sdf_1_keyed <- sdf_1 %>% mutate(key = regexp_extract(col2, "^(.*)/", 1))
```

apply left equi-join:

```
matched <- sdf_1_keyed %>% 
  left_join(sdf_2 %>% transmute(key = col2, id = col1), by="key")
```

and summarise

```
matched %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
   summarise(col3 = as.numeric(sum(as.numeric(!is.na(id)), na.rm = TRUE) > 0))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
# Groups:   col1
    col1 col2             col3
   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
 1     1 john.com/abcd       1
 2     5 rob.com/pqrs        1
 3     6 sam.com/tuvw        0
 4     9 bob.com/fghi        0
 5     3 paul.com/hijk       1
 6     4 george.com/lmno     0
 7     8 lenny.com/bcde      0
 8    10 tom.com/jklm        0
 9     2 ringo.com/defg      0
10     7 matt.com/xyza       0
# ... with more rows
```

A similar thing can be done with `RLIKE` condition:

```
candidates <- sdf_1 %>% spark_dataframe() %>% 
  sparklyr::invoke("crossJoin",
    sdf_2 %>% transmute(target = col2) %>% spark_dataframe()) %>% 
  sdf_register()

candidates %>% 
    mutate(matched = as.numeric(rlike(col2, target))) %>% 
    group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
    summarise(col3 = as.numeric(sum(matched, na.rm=TRUE) > 0))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
# Groups:   col1
    col1 col2             col3
   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
 1     1 john.com/abcd       1
 2     5 rob.com/pqrs        1
 3     6 sam.com/tuvw        0
 4     9 bob.com/fghi        0
 5     3 paul.com/hijk       1
 6     4 george.com/lmno     0
 7     8 lenny.com/bcde      0
 8    10 tom.com/jklm        0
 9     2 ringo.com/defg      0
10     7 matt.com/xyza       0
# ... with more rows
```

Finally you could extract unique values:

```
targets <- unique(as.character(df_2$col2))
```

and create SQL expression:

```
library(glue)

expr <- glue_collapse(glue("col2 rlike '{targets}'"), " OR ")

sdf_1 %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>%
  sparklyr::invoke(
    "selectExpr", 
    list("*", as.character(glue("{expr} as col3")))) %>% 
  sdf_register() %>%
  mutate(col3 = as.numeric(col3))
```

```
 # Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
 # Database: spark_connection
     col1 col2             col3
    <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
  1     1 john.com/abcd       1
  2     2 ringo.com/defg      0
  3     3 paul.com/hijk       1
  4     4 george.com/lmno     0
  5     5 rob.com/pqrs        1
  6     6 sam.com/tuvw        0
  7     7 matt.com/xyza       0
  8     8 lenny.com/bcde      0
  9     9 bob.com/fghi        0
 10    10 tom.com/jklm        0
 # ... with more rows
```

or R expression:

```
library(rlang)

rexpr <- glue_collapse(glue("rlike(col2, '{targets}')"), " | ")

sdf_1 %>% mutate(col3 = !!parse_quosure(glue("as.numeric({rexpr})")))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
    col1 col2             col3
   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
 1     1 john.com/abcd       1
 2     2 ringo.com/defg      0
 3     3 paul.com/hijk       1
 4     4 george.com/lmno     0
 5     5 rob.com/pqrs        1
 6     6 sam.com/tuvw        0
 7     7 matt.com/xyza       0
 8     8 lenny.com/bcde      0
 9     9 bob.com/fghi        0
10    10 tom.com/jklm        0
# ... with more rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much. These solutions are working very well for me. Still perplexed by the sudden recognition of the rlike function though.

Comment: You have to remember that all of that works because of SQL translation layer. No R functions are involved. If you try to test the same code on plain R `data.frame` it won't work.