# How to add column in dataframe using sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I have to mutate the `dataframe` and add column based on a certain word `Health` in a column. This code runs fine when I run it in `R` with `dplyr`, but it doesn't run when I use sparklyr. This is the first time I'm using `sparklyr`. How can I fix this?

```
bmk_tbl %>% add_column(healthcare = case_when(
                                          grepl("Health", .$OrganizationType) ~ 1, 
                                          TRUE ~ 0), .after = "OrganizationType")
```

I get the following error, and I don't know how to fix it

```
Error in if (nrow(df) != nrow(.data)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I'm not sure what to try so I tried doing something like this:

```
bmk_tbl %>% add_column(healthcare = case_when(
                                          (.$OrganizationType %in% c("Health") ~ 1), 
                                          TRUE ~ 0), .after = "OrganizationType")
```

but this won't work because there's no single word `Health` in the database. It's always mixed with some other multiple words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two unrelated problems here:

- Mutating primitives like `add_column` are applicable only to `data.frames`, and `tbl_spark` is not a one. This accounts for the following error:

  ```
  Error in if (nrow(df) != nrow(.data)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  ```

  In fact you should also see accompanying warning on the first invocation

  ```
  In addition: Warning message:
  `.data` must be a data frame in `add_column()`.
  ```

  The right function to use here is `mutate`.
- `grepl` is not [translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972504/why-cant-i-use-double-colon-operator-with-dplyr-when-the-dataset-is-in-sparklyr/52978496#52978496) into SQL primitive. [Instead you should use `grepl`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46289490/10465355)

Combined

```
data <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite=TRUE)

data %>% 
  mutate(match = case_when(
    Species %rlike% "tos" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ))
```

or simply

```
data %>%
    mutate(match = as.numeric(Species %rlike% "tos"))
```

Comment: Thank you.. In `instead you should use grepl` did you mean rlike? Is rlike a package or something that comes with sparklyr? I remember trying it but the error message I received was something related to `unknown function rlike`

Comment: Any functions you use here are not R objects. There are names translated (if possible) to underlying SQL dialect. The syntax you need is exactly as shown.